# Scala get a substring

Tags: string, scala, substring

I am trying to get a substring in scala. The string that I have is the following:

```
fromTo: NT=xxx_bt_bsns_m,OD=ntis,OS=wnd,SX=xs,SZ=ddp,
fromTo: NT=xds_bt2_bswns_m,OD=nis,OS=wnd,SX=xs,SZ=ddp,
fromTo: NT=xxa_bt1_b1ns_m,OD=nts,OS=nd,SX=xs,SZ=ddp
```

I just want to get a substring with:

```
 xxx_bt_bsns_m
```

Edit:
This substring can be other, for example ddd_zn1_ldk

So what i have to try to get all the string that start with NT and ends with a "," maybe?

I am starting with scala so for this reason i am having doubts with this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example strings, you can first match the pattern, and use a capture group for the part after `fromTo:`

The split the group 1 value on a comma, and filter the collection for values that start with `NT=` if you can have multiple values.

```
fromTo:\h+([A-Z]+=[^\s,=]+(?:,[A-Z]+=[^\s,=]+)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jFoomu/1)

In parts, the pattern matches:

- `fromTo:\h+` Match `fromTo:` and 1 or more horizontal spaces
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Z]+=[^\s,=]+` Match 1+ uppercase chars `=` and 1+ chars other than `,` `=` or whitespace chars
  - `(?:,[A-Z]+=[^\s,=]+)*` Optionally repeat the same perceded by a comma
- `)` Close group 1

For example

```
val s = "fromTo: NT=xxa_bt1_b1ns_m,OD=nts,OS=nd,SX=xs,SZ=ddp,NT=aaaaaa fromTo: NT=bbbbbbbbb"
val pattern = """fromTo:\h+([A-Z]+=[^\s,=]+(?:,[A-Z]+=[^\s,=]+)*)""".r

val result: Iterator[Array[String]] = pattern.findAllMatchIn(s).map(m =>
  m.group(1)
    .split(",")
    .filter(s => s.startsWith("NT=")))

result.foreach(a => a.foreach(println))
```

Output

```
NT=xxa_bt1_b1ns_m
NT=aaaaaa
NT=bbbbbbbbb
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot, but I have a doubt about the regex, if the Start of the string is not fromto and could be another one or even this, how would be?

Comment: @CloudSparkie In that case you can omit the anchors and use`\w+:\h+([A-Z]+=[^\s,=]+(?:,[A-Z]+=[^\s,=]+)*),?` See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0yVXh2/1/) and a [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/pqH2AR)   The example finds a single match, if you can have multiple occurrences of the same pattern, you can use `findAllIn` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, excuse me for response late, I am trying it and looks good. But with this i only get the first Match, so to get all the matches, would  i have to use findAllMatchIn? and the filter should change too, right?

Comment: @CloudSparkie That is right yes, but then you would have to omit the anchors `fromTo:\h+([A-Z]+=[^\s,=]+(?:,[A-Z]+=[^\s,=]+)*),?`

Comment: but my doubt is about the filter, if I use findAllMatchIn, the filter gives me an error because I am using an Iterator and not an option

Comment: @CloudSparkie You can use it like this https://ideone.com/Gevjbl returning an `Iterator[Array[String]]`

Answer (score 1):

We could use a regex replacement here:

```scala
val input = "fromTo: NT=xxx_bt_bsns_m,OD=ntis,OS=wnd,SX=xs,SZ=ddp"
val output = input.replaceAll("^.*\\bNT=([^,]+).*$", "$1")
println(output)  // xxx_bt_bsns_m
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Tim, sorry I forget to put that this string can change :| , i updated the post!

Comment: My answer doesn't change based on your edit, and it already covers your requirement.

Comment: Oh that's right! and if there are a multiple NT= how can I separate all and store in a DF for example?

Comment: That's not the original question you asked, nor what was answered.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I know it, but i forget to put it in the post :|